# Can I use nvarchar data type in plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql

Can I use nvarchar data type in plpgsql?

If so, do I have to follow the same syntax?

If not, then what is the alternative?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use the `text` or `varchar` types.

There's no need for, or support for, `nvarchar`. All PostgreSQL text-like types are always in the database's text encoding, you can't choose a 1-byte or 2-byte type like in MS SQL Server. Generally you just use a UTF-8 encoded DB, and everything works with no hassle.

Comment: Yeah! that's fine. Thank you so much Mr.Craig Ringer for your valuable support.

Comment: One more question raises in my mind here, can i use "max" value for varchar in plpgsql?                                                   Like for example varchar(max)?

Comment: @SarfarazMak That doesn't make any sense. What would that be supposed to mean? (Post a new question and explain it in detail please).